# Future.then returns unexpected null value

Tags: dart, future, dart-async

the following method prints a value of a key stored in Redis

```dart
Future<String> getValue(String connectionString, String key) {
  return RedisClient.connect(connectionString).then((RedisClient client) {
        client.get(key).then((value) => print(value));
      });
}
```

but when I try to print the value from main() the method getValue prints null instead of the value (as the method above):

```dart
library persistence;

Future<String> getValue(String connectionString, String key) {
  return RedisClient.connect(connectionString).then((RedisClient client) {
        client.get(key);
      });
}
```

-

```dart
import 'package:test/persistence.dart' as persistence;
main () {
  persistence.getValue(
                    "localhost:6379/0",
                    "key")
  .then((value) => print(value)); // **prints null.... WHY???**
}
```

It seems that the `.then((value) => print(value))` is executed too early.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: You can just use `.then(print);` and also try to add a `return`  at `client.get(key);`.

Comment: Hi Robert, you are right. Adding return at client.get(key) level, solves the problem. Thanks a lot:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `return` before `client.get(key)` or use the short method form `=> client.get(key)` then you don't need the `return`.

Comment: Perfect!! the short method '=>' makes it more clean the sintaxis: return RedisClient.connect(connectionString).then((RedisClient client) => client.get(key));  Thanks a lot:)